# Update table values from another table using joins?

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I am trying to update a collection of computer hostnames to match recently changed room numbers.  The hostnames in the database are formatted like FL-itf2106a with 2106 being the old room number.  I already have a list in another table that has the old and new room numbers on the same row.  I have been trying to strip all the non-numerics out of the string for the hostname and join that to the updates table unsuccessfully.

```
    UPDATE computers c
INNER JOIN updates u 
        ON u.old = (
                    SELECT NumericOnly(c.hostname)
                     WHERE hostname 
                      LIKE "%FC%"
                   )
       SET c.hostname = CONCAT('classf', u.new);
```

NumericOnly is a User function that removes all characters but numerics from a string.

I am trying to set the hostname column equal to classf + the new room number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd take my chances with something like

```
    UPDATE computers c
INNER JOIN updates u 
        ON u.old = NumericOnly(c.hostname) 
       SET c.hostname = CONCAT('classf', u.new)
     WHERE c.hostname LIKE "%FC%";
```

Comment: Looks like I still have some learning to go with MYSQL.  This is just the answer I was looking for.  Worked great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Postgresql version that worked for me:

```
update table1 set columnZ = newValue from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2
on t1.columnX = t2.columnY
where table1.uniqueID = t1.uniqueID
and t2.filterColumn = filterValue
```

http://johnstewien.wordpress.com/2010/03/15/doing-a-join-in-an-update-in-sql-for-postgresql/

This question comes up in the first few hits for "SQL UPDATE JOIN" on google.